# Regex Multiple Parenthases

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a pretty simple piece of regex code: `(\{)[^}]+(\})` , which only gets the first set of ({)[^}]+(}). Is there a way to get **all** sets of brackets?

Comment: How are you using that regex, what function are you using exactly?

Comment: just like `str.match(/(\{)[^}]+(\})/)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses)

Answer (score 0):

just add the global flag g

```js
let regexp = /(\{)[^}]+(\})/g;
```

Comment: huh, never knew there was a global variable